# Delete Firestore document created by a different user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am synchronising clocks in two JavaScript clients by writing to Firestore every second and then subscribing the second remote client / "slave" to the document.

This works fine and I can read the document changes in real time based on this method of creating the document reference:

```js
const useCloudTimer = (isMaster, opponentCCID, userCCID) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { localRemainingTimeMS, clockTimeOut } = useSelector((state) => state.clock);

    const timerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        timerRef.current = db.collection('timers').doc(`${isMaster
            ? userCCID + opponentCCID
            : opponentCCID + userCCID
            }`);

        dispatch(clock(CLOCK, { cloudTimerDbRef: timerRef.current }));
    }, []);

    const pushTimer = async (duration) => {
        try {
            await timerRef.current.set({ duration });
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error, 'cloud timer');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => { if (isMaster) pushTimer(localRemainingTimeMS); }, [localRemainingTimeMS]);

    const getTimer = async () => {
        try {
            const unsubscribeRemoteTimer = await timerRef.current.onSnapshot((doc) => {
                if (!clockTimeOut && doc.exists) {
                    const duration = Number(doc.data().duration);
                    dispatch(clock(CLOCK, { remoteRemainingTimeMS: duration }));
                }
            });
            if (clockTimeOut) unsubscribeRemoteTimer().then((arg) => console.log('unsubscribeRemoteTimer', arg));
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error, 'getTimer');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => { if (!isMaster) getTimer(); }, []);
};

export default useCloudTimer;
```

The problem is when I want to delete the document. If the client that did not create the document tries to delete it, what happens is that a new document is created for a split second with the same name, and then that one is deleted. Here is the exact moment this happens where you can see two documents with the same name:

[image]

A document is green when it's being written to and red when it's being deleted.

My document ref is being stored in redux and then used via the store when required:

```js
export const deleteCloudTimer = async (timerRef) => {
    if (timerRef) {
        try {
            await timerRef.delete();
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error, 'Error removing document: ');
        }
    }
};
```

How can my Firebase client app delete a document if it didn't create it?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks requiring precision timing especially with high amounts of reads/writes are not suggested for firestore. You might consider an alternative GCP product instead?

Comment: Thanks, which product would you recommend?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, maybe cloud tasks? 1 second resolution would be tough though.. Can I ask why you need such timing?

Comment: Ok thanks. It's actually a clock which is why it's once pers second. Since your answer I've been looking at AWS AppSync and graphQL. Google cloud products seem hard to integrate in to react native if it's not a firebase product and you're not running a server.